# PSQL replacement for stored procedure, too slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sqlperformance, postgresql-performance

I have `property`, each `property` has `contracts`, each `contract` has integer field `rental_area`.

Previously I had to get the `rental_area` of all contracts summed by property and this worked.

```
 SELECT 
        Sum(cr.rental_area)         total_property_rental_area,
        -- bunch of other cr fields
 FROM  appdata.contract_rental cr
        INNER JOIN appdata.domain_building b1 
                ON ( b1.building_id = cr.building_id ) 
        INNER JOIN appdata.domain_immovable im1 
                ON ( im1.immovable_id = b1.immovable_id ) 
 GROUP  BY im1.property_id
```

Now the logic changed, and contract has a list of `periods`, and one of those periods contain the `rental_area` of that contract. And finding that correct `period` needed some special logic.

I tried to join the logic to the query, but could not find a place, where to put it so I had to create stored procedure.

```
SELECT Sum(p.rental_area) total_property_rental_area 
       -- bunch of other cr fields
FROM   appdata.contract_rental cr 
       JOIN appdata.rental_period p 
         ON p.id = Get_current_period_id(cr.contract_rental_id, 
                   cr.end_date_actual) 
       INNER JOIN appdata.domain_building b1 
               ON ( b1.building_id = cr.building_id ) 
       INNER JOIN appdata.domain_immovable im1 
               ON ( im1.immovable_id = b1.immovable_id ) 
GROUP  BY im1.property_id
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION appdata.get_current_period_id(in contract_id_in bigint, in end_date_actual_in Date)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    period_id bigint;
BEGIN
    -- find the period that matches with end date or current date
    select id into period_id
       from rental_period
       where contract_id = contract_id_in
         and Coalesce(end_date_actual_in, Now()) >= start_date
       order by start_date desc  limit 1;
    -- if there was no period, just take the first one
    IF period_id is null THEN
        select id into period_id
           from rental_period
           where contract_id = contract_id_in
           order by start_date asc
           limit 1;
    END IF;

    return period_id;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

But now it is too slow, is there a way to put the period finding logic into the sql to make it faster, without using stored procedure? **The point is that, for reach contract, it has to only get single period based on the logic.**

Comment: Off-topic: you can avoid the `Coalesce(end_date_actual_in, Now())` constructs by making start_date and end_date not-NULLable and giving them default values of `-infinity` and `+infinity` .

Comment: @joop , but then I would have to check if the value is -infinity or +infinity instead of null, so I think performance wise it is same. Also in UI, they will then always be valued as some values and will be tried to display them there, instead of showing empty fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll out your stored procedure back into the main SQL, the primary hint being coalescing your 2 queries (if one is null then use the other)

Example: Instead of

```
p.id = Get_current_period_id(cr.contract_rental_id, 
               cr.end_date_actual)
```

Use:

```
p.pid = coalesce(
    (select rpx.id 
     from rental_period rpx
     where contract_id = cr.contract_rental_id
     and Coalesce(cr.end_date, Now()) >= start_date
     order by start_date desc  limit 1;
    ),
  ( select rpy.id 
       from rental_period rpy
       where contract_id = cr.contract_rental_id
       order by start_date asc
       limit 1;
  )
)
```

As per the comment below, the following index may also help:

```
 create index on rental_period (contract_id, start_date asc)
```

be sure to analyze the table afterward to update the statistics.

Comment: Wow it works, but I do not understand how? It is basically the same query, but it is much faster?

Comment: Stored procedures are so-called optimization "walls". The internal optimizer attempts to examine the process as a whole to figure out how best to get the results. When put together in one sql statement, the optimizer has more information and better understands what it's doing. The minute it hits a wall, it can optimize no further... so it can optimize the procedure AND SQL statement, just independently. Putting them together often results in better performance almost magically.

Comment: Those order by's and limit 1's could likely be optimized out as well, they will also perform better if indexed by ALL columns in the "where" field, with the right asc/desc order as well. If you're happy with the results, you may feel free to stop trying to optimize it. If you want it to look a little nicer, you can use a "with" statement to divide up the query into easier to digest pieces. (Look up CTE's or Common Table Expressions)